NoUiSlider React - How to dynamically set background of the slider background?
I'm trying to get a colorized slider at the current position of the dragger to get the result on the attached screenshot.
I followed this link:
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-colorpicker
But I'm still not able to get the correct results. I tried the following:
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
const sliderBackground = {
        background: `linear-gradient(to right, black ${percentage}%, white ${100 - percentage}%)`
    }
<Nouislider
                start={value}
                range={range}
                tooltips={false}
                format={format}
                onSlide={onChangeSlide.bind(this)}
                style={sliderBackground}
                keyboardSupport={keyboardSupport}
                onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            />

Does the NoUI slider have any build-in property for this (based on the docs https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-styling) or how can I achieve colorized slider at the current position of the dragger?

